# Parsing dates from OCRed files using dateparser library

Tags: python, date-parsing, dateparser

I want to extract dates from OCR images using the `dateparser` lib.

```
import dateparser
data = []
listOfPages = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/name/folder/test/*.tif")
for entry in listOfPages:
    text1 = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="deu"
        )
    text = re.sub(r'\n',' ', text1)     
    date1 = re.compile(r'(Dresden(\.|,|\s+)?)(.*)', flags = re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    date = date1.search(text)
    if date:
        dates = dateparser.parse(date.group(3), date_formats=['%d %m %Y'], languages=['de'], settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})
        
    else:
        dates = None
        if dates == None:
            dates = dateparser.parse(date.group(3), date_formats=['%d %B %Y'], locale = 'de', settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})
        else:
            dates = None

    data.append([text, dates])
    
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text', 'dates'])
print(df0)
```

Why am i getting error: NameError: name 'dates' is not defined

update: `TypeError: Input type must be str`

[image: updated sample tif]

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You are suppressing errors with `except: pass`. Some line before  the assignment to `dates` is throwing an exception so the assignment never happens, so the name never gets defined. This is why you should not suppress errors. Change `pass` to `raise` or a `print()` call or both to find the error.

Comment: thanks, BoarGules for the reminder. Now the error is `TypeError: Input type must be str` which points at the `date` variable. I thought the result of `date1.search(text)` would be a string or is it that regex span object thing?

Comment: First of all, there is no match for `(City(\.|,|\s+)?)(.*)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6x4Ca/1).  `date` is a match data object, not a string, but you are passing it to `dateparser.parse` as the first argument, you need to use `dateparser.parse(date.group(3)` as you want the value captured into `(.*)`. Also, `dateparser.parse(text, date_formats=['%d %m %Y'], languages=['de'], settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})` does not find anything. What is the actual text? Also, note you do not need try excet here at all.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor! If i dont `try:except` i get error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. If i keep it, it doesent give me any error anymore but also returns all `dates` values as `None`. `.group(3)` is the right one though, according to  https://regex101.com/r/ah5b03/1

Comment: Ok, I have it working now.

Comment: I updated the picture with one of my subset. Do you know why that one isnt working? https://regex101.com/r/HF6yRn/1 Otherwise your solution captures all the dates correctly! Very well done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `date` is a match data object. Also, I am not sure `dateparser.parse` does what you need. I'd recommend [`datefinder` package](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/) to extract dates from text.

This is the regex I'd use:

```py
\bDresden(?:[.,]|\s+)?(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LGLmS7/1). It matches `Dresden` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary), `(?:[.,]|\s+)?` is a non-capturing optional group matching `,`, `.` or one or more whitespaces, and then captures into Group 1 any zero or more chars (`re.DOTALL` allows `.` to match line separators, too).

Here is the Python snippet that seems to yield expected matches:

```py
import pytesseract, dateparser, glob, re
import pandas as pd
import datefinder
from pytesseract.pytesseract import Image

imgpath = r'1.tif'
data = []
listOfPages = glob.glob(r"C:/Users/name/folder/test/*.tif")
listOfPages = [imgpath]
for entry in listOfPages:
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(
            Image.open(entry), lang="deu"
        )

    dates = []
    date = re.search(r'\bDresden(?:[.,]|\s+)?(.*)', text, re.DOTALL)
    if date:
        dates = [t.strftime("%d %B %Y") for t in datefinder.find_dates(date.group(1))]
        #dates = dateparser.parse(date.group(1), date_formats=['%d %m %Y'], languages=['de'], settings={'STRICT_PARSING': True})

    data.append([text, dates])
    
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns =['raw_text', 'dates'])
print(df0)
```

With your sample image, I get

```
                                            raw_text                               dates
0  Sächsischer Landtag DRUCKSACHE , 1972\n2. Wahl...  [17 October 1995, 18 October 1995]
```